# How can I use a Joomla user database in a mobile application?

Tags: java, php, android, database, joomla

I'm coding a website for a client as well as an app that mirrors the site. Does anyone have a good understanding on how to implement users created on the Joomla site and use that same database on an App for android? The app and site will allow users to change and add new data and the data must be current on the site and the app.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Joomla?

Comment: It is version 3.3.6.

Comment: I'm going to put a comment because I don't have a well defined answer, but what you want is more than accessing the user tables, you want to access the authentication system as a whole. What you want to do is to provide authentication as a service. There are different ways to do this (e.g. make joomla an oauth server) but perhaps the simplest is to make a stand alone authentication provider application on the Joomla framework.  There are a few frustrating pieces of that in some of the JUser packages, so you may need to override some methods but it's still the easiest thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Hoicoi Api](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-apps/28130) in JED,
its an extension that retrieve data or user authentication from Joomla! site and converted all information into JSON format. Never tried it but I think it could help you to get started via the user authentication.